# How to lock child stage until new child stage get closed

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I was able to lock parent Stage until child stage get closed using below code.
I tried below code to lock parent Stage and  successfully done.

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(primaryStage);

public static Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    ...
}
```

The above code is used to lock the parent Stage.
But how to lock child Stage if I have a root child Stage?

Comment: What do you mean by `root child Stage`?

Comment: Sorry actually i don't know the exact word... I mean another stage in child Stage.For example I have a new button in child stage, I have a controller class for new button, when i press new button a new Stage appears.How to lock child stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Modality enum defined the 3 types NONE, WINDOW_MODAL and APPLICATION_MODAL. When using APPLICATION_MODAL a window will be modal to all other windows in the application. This means that it will be always on top and you can't use another window of your application while this window is opened.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot!!! I just changed dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL) to dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL for the new child node and it Works !!!

Comment: Perfect :) Can you upvote and mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

NONE,WINDOW_MODAL,APPLICATION_MODAL Just change  Node.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); Makes inaccessible to child Stage